# Code inspection is not working in Android studio (power save is already off)

Tags: android, android-studio

I added random words but android studio is not red highlighting them. At the bottom corner, the power saver mode is also nots selected.

[image]

Comment: Did you try invalidate caches/restart?

Comment: yes, I did that. I also reinstalled android studio